# Are there disadvantages to activating auto-reload in TF2?

Tags: team-fortress-2

In Team Fortress 2, there is an option to automatically reload your weapon as soon as you stop firing. Furthermore, reloading can be interrupted by firing, and (except for the Force-a-Nature) reloading does not waste ammo.

**Are there any reasons to *disable* auto-reloading, or to use the manual reload key?**

I can only think of two itsy-bitsy ones:

- Visual distraction (and if that's a problem, better off disabling viewmodels?)
- As a Spy, creating opportunities to fake-reload

Comment: It seems like you're searching for a problem here, rather than posting based on an actual problem ([FAQ]: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face").

Comment: @Matthew I think this is a very good question, about pros and cons of a specific option. I've slightly edited it, though, to make it appear less as the kind of questions you describe - because in my opinion, it really isn't.

Comment: @MatthewRead How about "Can I improve my gameplay/Am I missing out on something by turning off auto-reload?"

Comment: @Oak I disagree with your edit: I gave two reasons, so there are *some*. Irrelevant to my particular playstyle, as it happens, but there are some. So I'm asking if there are more.

Comment: If you disagree, *please* edit it to be better :-) I was just trying to turn it into more of an "advantages vs disadvantages" question, since I think it was phrased a little strange before. And yes, grammar mistake, I blame me doing this from my phone :-)

Comment: @Oak But it's all speculative; the question doesn't present any reason to believe that there are any significant cons. You could ask questions just like this about every alternative way of doing things in any game.

Comment: A guy who regularly plays soldier on a server I frequent claims that there is a difference in timing, and  the manual control is better.  He is the highest ranked on the sever and has plays in competitve leagues. Though I don't have any hard details for you.

Comment: I can speak from personal experience, and that of my friends who play competitively, that there is no reason not to use auto-reload unless you're a spy who wants to fake reload. In fact, my competitive friends insist that you should always use auto-reload with viewmodels turned off. He told me I'd notice massive improvement in my play when I started using auto-reload and he was right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have auto-reload disabled in my spy.cfg because when I'm using the Ambassador, the reload animation obscures the reticule, which slows me down when I'm trying to set up  the second headshot needed to finish off some of the tougher classes.

In your spy.cfg file (Steam\steamapps\\team fortress 2\tf\cfg\spy.cfg):

```
cl_autoreload "0"
```

In all the other classes:

```
cl_autoreload "1"
```

(By the way, you're right, viewmodels off would also solve this problem, I just like them better on.)

Comment: A code snippet would be nice.

Comment: I'll put one up tomorrow.

Comment: And when I said "Tomorrow", I meant in [Valve Time](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Valve_Time)

Comment: @SteveV. And one year later....still not enough for Valve Time?

Comment: @Retrosaur - All right...I deserved that.

Comment: @Retrosaur - there you go!  "Tomorrow" = "a year and fifteen days later".  Sounds about right for Valve.

Comment: @SteveV. - The Spy's revolver reload animation has been changed to no longer obscure most of the screen (as of Gunmettle 2015 IIRC): do you still leave auto-reload off for this reason or should your top point be amended?

Answer (score 6):

Auto reload can be a put-off in some situations.  For example, if you're a scout with the Force-a-Nature, or the Soda Popper, guns that when reloading will discard all shells loaded, turning on auto reload wastes bullets.

Turning off auto-reload will prevent you from wasting the bullets, and help conserve ammo in otherwise tight situations.

Answer (score -2):

There are a few reasons to not auto reload. As stated above, it can waste ammo with a certain few weapons. Also, some reload animations can obscure view, much like revolvers and rocket launchers (excpetion being the Original).

Other than that, it is all opinion based. There are plenty of weapons that only have one shot per load, so they will already auto load after firing a shot, and some that do not even need to reload, so they are not included.

(I disabled it becuase I found it annoying, and prefered to reload when I wanted to reload.)

Other than the chance to loose a shot on two specific weapons, everything else is opinion based. Some people might complain about the obscured view, while others might be fine with it. Some people might like to be more in control of the game, while some others are fine with reloading when ever. Mostly opinion based.

NOTE: This could easily change if there was a weapon that had altered stats depending on the number of bullets left in the clip, or a gun that punished you for reloading with bullets left in the clip.

Answer (score -3):

Auto reload can be annoying - if you are in a sticky situation and you need to pop a few more rockets or stickies you might have a problem with reloading.

Comment: -1 this is not true at all, as you can shoot through reloading unlike most games.